How Can I use numpy and pandas on Python 3.8 32 bits?
I have numpy 1.2.4 and pandas 2.0.3 running my project perfect on PC with Windows 7 64 bits with Python 3.8 64, but in the laptop with Windows 7 32 bits and python 3.8 32 bits the proyect doesn´t run. How Can I use numpy and pandas on Python 3.8 32 bits??
When I try to run the program only close "by an error" but doesn´t say Which Error. Please Help!!
Before hand thanks by your insteresting comments.

What have you tried? There is a pandas-2.0.3-cp38-cp38-win32.whl, so you should be able to just create a virtualenv and pip install pandas==2.0.3 in the 32-bit Python 3.8 environment.

I believe the real problem is numpy, pandas depends of numpy.

You're still not telling us what you've tried. You should also tell us the actual version of Numpy you're running – NumPy 1.2.4 does not exist.

Excuse me, version numpy 1.24.4

numpy-1.24.4-cp38-cp38-win32.whl also exists.

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

I would put it , but the program close and doesn´t say the error, I said it in my question, but I know the problem is numpy, if I comment import pandas the program run.

I answer myself, I degrade from numpy 1.24.4 to 1.23.5 and it solved it. This was suggested in:
https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/24832
